# GraphQL : queries : cannot get data from MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express-graphql

I get this error :

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Type Query must define one or more fields."
    }
  ]
```

when I run my query  :

```
{
  user{

   _id 
    name
    username
    password
    email
    date_inscription
    profession

  }
}
```

I have the same example then
 https://blog.cloudboost.io/a-crud-app-with-apollo-graphql-nodejs-express-mongodb-angular5-2874111cd6a5

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your query doesn't return any fields.  Make sure that under graphql/queries/user/user.js you have at least one field defined like this:

`const UserListType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserList',
  fields() {
    return {
      id: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
        description: "Unique identifier of the User"
      }
    }
  }
})`

The other piece to check is that you have properly exported the query in graphql/queries/index.js like this:

```
// Users
const listUsers = require('./user/listUsers')

module.exports = {

  // Users
  listUsers
}
```